# Group by, Summarize, MAX, and count in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Below is the data I have which I want to merge by updating the most recent changes to the record and taking the groupby of SUB_NO and LOAN column.

```
SUB_NO  ON_DATE ST_DATE ND_DATE N_SEQ_NO    E_SEQ_NO    N_CODE  ACTV_AMT    L_SEQ_NO    FEATURE_CODE    LOAN      
123     7/19/17 6/18/17 7/17/17 916       16           O         15.63    153         INSTALLMENT     152       
123     8/21/17 7/18/17 8/17/17 916       16           O         15.63    154         INSTALLMENT     152      
124     6/20/17 5/18/17 6/17/17 916       17           O         15.63    152         OTHER           153
```

Expected Output:

```
SUB_NO  ON_DATE ST_DATE ND_DATE N_SEQ_NO    E_SEQ_NO    N_CODE  ACTV_AMT    L_SEQ_NO    FEATURE_CODE    LOAN    COUNT  
123     8/21/17 6/18/17 8/17/17 916       16           O         15.63    154         INSTALLMENT     152       2
124     6/20/17 5/18/17 6/17/17 916       17           O         15.63    152         OTHER           153       0


library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% 
  filter(FEATURE_CODE == "INSTALLMENT")  %>%
  group_by(SUB_NO,LOAN) %>%
  slice(which.max(as.Date(ON_DATE, '%m/%d/%Y'))) %>%
  slice(which.max(as.Date(ND_DATE, '%m/%d/%Y'))) %>%
  slice(which.max(L_SEQ_NO)) %>%
  summarize(COUNT = n())
```

I am getting output as:

```
LOAN COUNT
152  2
```

Can anyone help me in getting the desired output?

My main goal is for each SUB_NO which consists of multiple transactions with different FEATURE_CODE involving INSTALLMENT. I want to identify the count of INSTALLMENT transactions and merge the data into 1 record with INSTALLMENT feature_code with an initial start date and most recent update date.

Comment: For a start: if you filter for `FEATURE_CODE == "INSTALLMENT"`, you're not going to get the row with `SUB_NO` = 124 (where `FEATURE_CODE` = `OTHER`) in your output.

Comment: @neilfws I am not worried about the records other than INSTALLMENT. If they stay as they are and filled with NA in count column that is fine.

Comment: The point is that with your current filters, those rows will not appear at all.

Comment: @neilfws then I should put IF condition there instead of filter I believe

Comment: Also unclear why the second count is expected to be 0. Should it not be 1?

Comment: Get rid of the `filter` line, because you want to keep your `OTHER` feature code. If you want the summary to count only `INSTALLMENT` feature codes, instead of `COUNT = n()` use `COUNT = sum(FEATURE_CODE == INSTALLMENT)`.

Comment: @Gregor But it is removing some of the feature_codes

Comment: Make your example show that. I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @Gregor you explanation is working correctly. I have missing values in some of the columns that are removing the feature codes. If I consider columns which don't have null values it is working properly. Can you help me how can I handle missing values

Comment: You can always add `na.rm = T` inside `sum()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @gregor pointed out, an example would be more useful. Here's what I understood you want:

1. subset data by `FEATURE_CODE = INSTALLMENT`
2. Group all records by `SUB_NO` and `LOAN`
3. Merge records from step 2 such that the final dataset contains the latest `ON_DATE`, `ND_DATE` and initial `ST_DATE` for individual entries (grouped in step 2).

I'd recommend a `data.table` approach, which in my experience, is cleaner and faster.

I converted the dates to an object of class `date` using `as.Date`:

```
dat$ST_DATE <- as.Date(dat$ST_Date)
```

and then used the following code:

```
dat[FEATURE_CODE == "INSTALLMENT", .(ON_DATE = max(ON_DATE), 
                                     ST_DATE = min(ST_DATE), 
                                     ND_DATE = max(ND_DATE)), 
    by = .(SUB_NO, LOAN)]
```

and the output is:

```
   SUB_NO LOAN    ON_DATE    ST_DATE    ND_DATE
1:    123  152 2017-08-21 2017-06-18 2017-08-17
```

which meets requirements 1, 2 and 3.

You can add other variables to the second list above to perform any other operations you may want. Hope this is helpful!